# Spring Tool Suite.HTTP Status 404 -The requested resource is not available

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I'm working with Spring Tool Suite and I want to be redirected to a jsp (rapports.jsp) from sevelet.But I can't do so .I get this error:

HTTP Status 404 - /rapports.jsp
type Status report

message: /rapports.jsp

description:The requested resource is not available.

**This is my controller:**

```
package com.mycompany.myapp;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseStatus;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;

import javax.servlet.ServletConfig;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

import javax.sql.*;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import org.apache.tools.ant.util.Base64Converter;
import javax.servlet.ServletConfig;

@Controller
public class HomeController extends HttpServlet {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView adminPage() {
ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView();

model.setViewName("authentification");

return model;}



@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.POST)
  public void service(HttpServletRequest request,  HttpServletResponse response)
              throws IOException, ServletException{

              String Str1 = request.getParameter("smya");  
              String Str2 = request.getParameter("mdps");
              System.out.println(Str1);
              System.out.println(Str2);

try {
    URL url = new URL("http://pc-demo-bi:8090/jasperserver-pro/rest/login?j_username="+Str1+"&j_password="+Str2);
    HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
    conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");


                    if (conn.getResponseCode() != 200) {
                        throw new RuntimeException("Failed : HTTP error code : "
                                + conn.getResponseCode());
                    }


                        System.out.println("connected");
                        response.sendRedirect("/rapports.jsp");


                    conn.disconnect();

                  } catch (MalformedURLException e) {

                    e.printStackTrace();

                  } catch (IOException e) {

                    e.printStackTrace();

                  }

                }

}
    as you see I have used: response.sendRedirect("/rapports.jsp") to do so.
```

**and this is my Web.xml:**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

<!-- The definition of the Root Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<!-- Creates the Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<!-- Processes application requests -->
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

this is my rapport.jsp

```
<title>hahahah</title>
</head>
<body>
 Welcome!!

</body>
</html>
```

thanks in advance if you have any suggestion.

Comment: Can you please show the stacktrace?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personally, I dont think you need to extend HttpServlet.  Try something like what i've put below.  Assuming you have a valid view resolver (Spring or otherwise, I prefer [Apache Tiles](http://tiles.apache.org/)), returning just the name of the JSP page "rapports" will redirect the user.  You can also use the annotation @RequestAttribute to get Str1 and Str2 from the HttpServletRequest, rather than injecting it into the method.

```
@Controller
public class HomeController {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView adminPage() {
        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView();
        model.setViewName("authentification");
        return model;
    }
    @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public void service(@RequestAttribute("smya") Str1, @RequestAttribute("mdps") Str2){
        System.out.println(Str1);
        System.out.println(Str2);
        try {
            URL url = new URL("<code>http://pc-demo-bi:8090/jasperserver-pro/rest/login?j_username="+Str1+"&j_password="+Str2</code>);
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
            if (conn.getResponseCode() != 200) {
                throw new RuntimeException("Failed : HTTP error code : "
                + conn.getResponseCode());
            }
            System.out.println("connected");
                return("rapports");
                conn.disconnect();
        } 
        catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Hopefully that makes sense!

Comment: Thank you for your response.I did as you said.I add : return new ModelAndView("rapports"); at the end of the class and I diclared a controller for the rapports.jsp and it works fine.Thanks for your help.

Comment: Please can you up vote / select it as the correct answer, if it answered your question? Cheers